# Synchronizing my Yarn version & the Yarn version used by buildModules

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to get a system running using the `localhost` for entry, therefore, I installed the recommended versions of **Node.js**, and **Yarn**. The problem I am having at this point is `buildModules` uses **Yarn `v1.22.5`**. I had previously installed the latest version of yarn but now, as required, I installed **Yarn `v1.22.5`** but it still shows **Yarn `v1.22.19`**.

```
xyz@xyz-MacBook-Air cbioportal-frontend % yarn run buildModules
yarn run v1.22.5
$ lerna run build --ignore=cbioportal-frontend --stream
lerna notice cli v3.19.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter excluding "cbioportal-frontend"
lerna info filter [ '!cbioportal-frontend' ]
lerna info Executing command in 9 packages: "yarn run build"
cbioportal-ts-api-client: error cbioportal-ts-api-client@0.9.43: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "1.22.5". Got "1.22.19"
cbioportal-ts-api-client: error Commands cannot run with an incompatible environment.
cbioportal-ts-api-client: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 1 in 'cbioportal-ts-api-client'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 3 child processes to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Eventhough, when I check the version of yarn, it still shows **Yarn `v1.22.19`**

```
xyz@xyz-MacBook-Air cbioportal-frontend % yarn -v
1.22.5
```

I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the exact version of yarn to use in your project using

```
yarn policies set-version 1.22.19
```

This will create a folder `.yarn/releases` with the yarn js file. Make sure to commit that file into git. Then whenever you run `yarn` in the project, you'll always use the same version.

see [docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies#enforcing-yarns-version-across-your-project-)

Comment: Thanks, I set the version to 1.22.5 (as required by buildModules) but is still shows `cbioportal-ts-api-client: error cbioportal-ts-api-client@0.9.43: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "1.22.5". Got "1.22.19"
cbioportal-ts-api-client: error Commands cannot run with an incompatible environment.` Any idea what might be causing this? yarn -v gives 1.22.5